# Query Performance When Using Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with roughly 200 million rows. The table contains a number of columns, but at the moment only the primary key and a non clustered index based on the datetime column for indexes.

This first query will return zero rows, in less than a second.

```
SELECT *
FROM GenericTable
WHERE GenericDate > '01-01-1753' AND GenericDate <= '01-29-1753'
```

This query takes an excessively long time to return zero rows, approximately two minutes.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '01-01-1753'
SET @endDate = '01-29-1753'

SELECT *
FROM GenericTable
WHERE GenericDate > @startDate AND GenericDate <= @endDate
```

Using a date range that contains data, the performance is a little better? The first query will return 1000s of rows in less than a second, the second query still requires 30 seconds or more to return the same data.

EDIT: I also had it show me the execution plan, and the second query is not using the index?

1st Query:

```
Select <- Nested Loops (Inner Join) - 0% <- Index Seek (NonClustered) - 0%
                                         <- Key Lookup (Clustered) - 100%
```

2nd Query:

```
Select <- Parallelism (Gather Streams) - 10% <- Clustered Index Scan (Clustered) - 90%
```

Comment: What datatype is GenericDate?  Also you should use the ANSI date format yyy-mm-dd to avoid any localization issues. (i.e. '1753-01-29')

Comment: @SeanLange GenericDate is datetime, not null.

Comment: Is this in a stored proc where the dates are passed in as parameters? It sounds a LOT like parameter sniffing but I don't know the context where this query is executing.

Comment: Any chance you could post the execution plans as attachments? They contain mountains of important information.

Comment: @SeanLange At the moment I'm simply running it from Management Studio in a new query window. I initially noticed the performance issue in a loop I had created to move data, but the performance issue exists outside of the loop as shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a well known issue with execution plan caching and parameter
sniffing.

Quoting from [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2008/02/25/parameter-sniffing-pt-2/)

> A while back I wrote about parameter sniffing, the situation where SQL
>   compiles and caches an execution plan that is appropriate for a
>   certain value of a parameter, but is non optimal for other values.
>   There’s another side to parameter sniffing though – when the optimiser
>   can’t sniff at all.
>
> When a batch is submitted to the optimiser, the value of any
>   parameters (from stored procedure, auto parametrisation or
>   sp_executesql) are known to the optimiser. So are the value of any
>   constants used in the SQL statement. The value of local variables,
>   however, are not.
>
> **When the value of a variable used in the where clause is not known, the optimiser has no idea what value to use to estimate the number
>   of affected rows**. Hence, it has no idea how many rows from the table
>   will satisfy the condition.

Comment: And adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will allow the values to be sniffed.

Comment: @MartinSmith Absolutely